# conda update causes ImportError: No module named tqdm

Tags: python, conda, tqdm

Whenever I try to update anything using conda, I get an error: `ImportError: No module named tqdm`. Here's the full traceback:

```
$ conda update conda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/anaconda2/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 150, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1335, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1046, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1090, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1101, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1171, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "/Users/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "/Users/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "/Users/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
  File "/Users/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_package_handling/api.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tqdm
ImportError: No module named tqdm
```

However, when I try to install tqdm with pip, it says it is already installed:

```
$ pip install tqdm
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (4.32.2)
```

I am using Python 2.7 on MacOS Mojave with no virtual environments. How can I fix conda?

EDIT:
I also tried: `python -m pip install tqdm` but it says requirement already satisfied.

Then I tried: `/Users/user/anaconda2/bin/python -m pip install tqdm` but it also says requirement already satisfied: `Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in ./anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (4.31.1)`

Comment: you have two Pythons and `pip` uses different Python then `conda` - see pathes in messages. You should have different `pip` installed with `conda` and you may have to use full path to pip or try `python -m pip install tqdm`

Comment: I tried that and still wasn't able to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up removing and reinstalling anaconda, which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use `conda` to install `tqdm`, something is seriously messed up.

In the best of cases, it's only about environment variables. Are you setting PYTHONPATH or similar? That could interfere with `conda` finding its own packages.

1. Check your environment variables, don't set anything Python.
2. Execute `conda activate base`.
3. Check that `python` now is the one from the conda base environment.
4. Call `conda install`.

In the worst of cases, you somehow uninstalled or broke a package that `conda` needs. In this case, re-install Miniconda from scratch in a different directory. You should use Miniconda3 (or Anaconda3) this time, as Python 2 is only half a year away from its end of life.
Afaik, `conda` is able to mange existing environments from a previous installation, but I've never tried to use that feature.

If you haven't been using conda environments, but installed everything into the conda base environment, and that environment is messed up, I have no idea how to recover. You should always create custom conda environments for your projects.

Answer (score 0):

**for ubuntu 18.04**

i faced the same issue on jupyter notebook, however the current apt install builds the 4.19 as latest which was bugged out for me.

Here are my steps for the solution:

Download the desired newer version
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tqdm/

cd to deb file location

sudo dpkg -i <filename.deb>